# How can I get text from within a nested <dl><dt>?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am new to web scraping, so my apologies in advance if I'm misunderstanding anything...

I am trying to get data from ESPN. Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://espn.go.com/nba/teams'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
tables = soup.find_all('dl')

teams = []
prefix_1 = []
prefix_2 = []
teams_urls = [] 

for table in tables:
    lis = table.find_all('dt', text=False)
    print lis
    for li in lis:
        info = dt
        teams.append(info.text)
        url = info['href']
        teams_urls.append(url)
        prefix_1.append(url.split('/')[-2])
        prefix_2.append(url.split('/')[-1])

print (teams)
```

When I print at various points, i am getting empty brackets [] as a return. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to fetch exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting the team names from the menu, but the actual page content contains teams also.

Let's use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get to the each team link on the page. As a result, let's construct a list of dictionaries with team names and urls inside:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://espn.go.com/nba/teams'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

teams = []
for link in soup.select('div.mod-table div.mod-content ul li h5 a[href]'):
    teams.append({
        'name': link.text,
        'url': link['href']
    })

print(teams)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {'name': u'Boston Celtics', 'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bos/boston-celtics'},
    {'name': u'Brooklyn Nets', 'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bkn/brooklyn-nets'},
    ...
    {'name': u'Utah Jazz', 'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/utah/utah-jazz'}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am running into the same issue I faced with another piece of code. This is only returning 12 teams: [{'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bos/boston-celtics', 'name': u'Boston Celtics'}, {'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/bkn/brooklyn-nets', 'name': u'Brooklyn Nets'}, {'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/ny/new-york-knicks', 'name': u'New York Knicks'}, {'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/phi/philadelphia-76ers', 'name': u'Philadelphia 76ers'}... {'url': 'http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/cle/cleveland-cavaliers', 'name': u'Cleveland Cavaliers'}]

Comment: @user3453024 quick check: install lxml (`pip install lxml`) and run the code again. Thanks.

Comment: I think I installed lxml. When I ran it from the terminal I got:

$ pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: When i ran the code again, I still get len = 12. Do I need to add anything to the code to take advantage of lxml?

Comment: Bamm! That did it. Thanks a lot!

If you have a second, what does the `headers = {'User-Agent` bit do?

Comment: @user3553024 this is how we pretend we are a real user using a real browser :)